# Differentiate between "start" and "halfway through the question" on the Questions screen

Tags: feature-request, questions

Some of the question excepts on the Questions screen begin at the start of the question text, while others begin halfway through the question.

[image]

The first shows the top of the question text, while the second begins in the middle of a sentence.

Why is that? Since these excepts are how I decide which questions to visit and which to ignore, it would be better IMHO if they all just showed the top of the question.
Or if they at least indicated somehow that they show the middle, maybe by putting an ellipsis in front.

Comment: I can't replicate what you're seeing here. that question is currently on page 21: http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=21&sort=newest and doesn't display like that. similarly by one of the tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responsive-design it displays fine.

Comment: Interesting. So the excepts are formatted differently under different circumstances. Must test more.

Answer (score 11):

Ok, I've managed to find something that may or may not be related to this.

After trying to find [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203571/responsive-grid-2x3-to-3x2), I looked at the words that proceeded the trimmed sentence.

> Can anyone explain how to get this structure?

If you use part of this as a search: "Can anyone explain how to get" then it shows numerous trimmed results.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Can+anyone+explain+how+to+get

Perhaps the search criteria is used to find the actual section containing the terms in posts?

Comment: I find that the issue I showed only happens if I search for something. Apparently it tries to show the search argument in context, so that's when it cuts off the top of the text - when the first part of the question doesn't contain the word. Anyway, thanks for showing me that it only happens under some circumstances; I wasn't aware.

Comment: @MrLister that makes more sense.